# How to rerun failed selenium-rc test script?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have written a selenium RC test script in PHP. There are some conditions when my script get ends if element not found on the page. So, my question is can we re-run that scripts if it gets failed?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to find out why the tests failed the first time, but presuming you are using PHPUnit to run the tests then it is technically possible...

Firstly, phpunit has a --repeat option,

Or secondly...

In the test case, you can use ->onNotSuccessfulTest() to call ->runBare() to rerun the test, something like this:

```
class yourTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    // ... 

    static public $retryCount = 0;

    public function onNotSuccessfulTest(\Exception $e)
    {

        // Rethrow tests which failed due to being marked as skipped or incomplete
        if ($e instanceof /* Put skipped or Incomplete classes here */) {
            throw $e;
        }

        if (self::$retryCount < 3) {
            self::$retryCount++;
            return $this->runBare();
        } else {
            self::$retryCount = 0;
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Again, you really want to investigate why the tests are failing, but what you asked is possible!